# Thread vs Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on C# Windows Application and I need to communicate with a device.
While I need to send command to device and receive response from it. In this feature I need to continuously send command and receive response from the device. \

**For this which will be better to use , background worker or thread?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Backgroundworker` has its own advantages like it uses thread from `Thread Pool` and it is for specific purpose, which is to do time consuming job in the background, also it is very easy to use. In `Backgroundworker` you have `RunWorkerCompleted` event which will be on the main thread, so you can update your view in that. And expensive stuff you can run under `DoWork` event. DoWork run on the background thread from the Thread Pool.

> I need to continuously send command and receive response from the
>   device.

For your requirement, I suggest you to check [TaskSheduler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/591271/A-Simple-Scheduler-in-Csharp).

Comment: I want to use Backgroundworker for improve an execution of an algorithm, it is advisable, or is better use an other approach